# timing the amount of time focused on a tab with chrome.tab api with chrome extension

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to store information relating to how long a person stays on a specific tab / URL.

Using the chrome API - https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/#type-Tab - I can trace the active and the highlighted information of a tab to do this.

I'm currently tracing a few different datapoints with my extension, as below, and would love to be able to trace how long I am on a specific tab (so how long I am on that tab specifically), as well as how often I am moving between tabs or creating new ones.

```
export type TAB_USAGE = {
  tabId: number;
  index?: number;
  highlighted: boolean;
  url: string;
  startTime: string;
  endTime?: string;
  startFocus?: string;
  endFocus?: string;
};

const getHostname = (url: string) => {
  // use URL constructor and return hostname
  return new URL(url).hostname;
};

export function enableTabListener(
  socket: any,
  currentPages: TAB_USAGE[],
  visitedPages: Partial<TAB_USAGE>[]
) {


  chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(
   
  });



  setInterval(async () => {
      console.log('sent tab data:', visitedPages);
  }, 50000);
}
```

I'm not 100% sure on the best approach here - I was thinking, do a check to see if the old data is active versus the new data is not?

so something like,

```
if (tabExisting.highlighted != tab.highlighted) {
//set endFocus?
}
```

When doing this approach, it doesn't appear to work, tabExisting coming out as null basically a lot of the time.

Or use another listener API so that when highlight changes, there's a counter set per hour somewhere? I'd love to see how many tabs, how often I'm switching between them, staying on one of them, on a per hour basis really, trying to work out a good way to do that.

Love some feedback here - my brain is a bit fried from staring at this documentation and would love some guidance.

Comment: AFAICT all the code is correct, including the first one if socketInstance is a property on globalThis, so the problem must be something else. What do you mean by "injected into the background script"? Injection is not supported there. Also, you can debug the code in devtools, set breakpoints and inspect the variables to see what actually happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is somewhat correct. However, the kind of activity you want to track I would change the type `TAB_USAGE` to:

```
export type FocusPeriod = {
  startTime: string,
  endTime: string
}

export type TAB_USAGE = {
  tabId: number;
  index?: number;
  active?: boolean;             //we're using active instead of highlighted
  url?: string;                 //notice url is now optional
  startTime: string;
  endTime?: string;
  focus?: Array<FocusPeriod>;   //storing multiple focus events of a tab
};
```

since one would be switching between tabs a lot and there would be multiple focus periods for a specific tab. Also note that `url` is now optional as we'll be listening to `.onActivated` event where `url` might not be available in the callback.

Now, in order to track the switching between tabs, I'd use `.onActivated` event instead of `.onHighlighted` event. Please mind the difference between an `active` tab and a `highlighted` tab.

> An active tab is always highlighted. There is only one active tab per window. You can have several highlighted tabs in a same window. But then all highlighted tabs are not active. Example: select a tab, hold your Shift key, and select another tab. The last tab clicked will become the active tab for this window, but all tabs between them (including the two limit ones) are now highlighted.

A listener on `.onActivated` event can be added like this:

```
chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(
  (activeInfo: object) => {
    const previousActiveTabIndex = currentPages.findIndex((page) => page.active);
    if(previousActiveTabIndex !== -1) {
      currentPages[previousActiveTabIndex].active = false;
      const focusLength = currentPages[previousActiveTabIndex].focus.length;
      currentPages[previousActiveTabIndex].focus[focusLength - 1].endTime = new Date().toISOString();
    }
    const newActiveTabIndex = currentPages.findIndex((page) => page.tabId === activeInfo.tabId);
    if(newActiveTabIndex > 0) {
      currentPages[newActiveTabIndex].active = true;
      currentPages[newActiveTabIndex].focus.push({
        startTime: new Date().toISOString(),
        endTime: ''
      });
    }
    else {
      currentPages = [
        ..currentPages,
        {
          tabId: activeInfo.tabId;
          active: true;
          startTime: new Date().toISOString();
          focus: [{ startTime: new Date().toISOString(), endTime: '' }]; 
        }
      ]
    }
  }
)
```

If you're only interested in tracking the tabs that the user actually visits the above code should work just fine for you. Though there are cases where we do `Cmd+Click` or `Ctrl+Click` to open a url in a new tab which will not make the newly created tab active. And what if the user never selects that tab, you won't be able to track it even when the user closes that tab due to this condition: `if (tabExists)` in your `.onRemoved` event handler function. For those cases, we should add the `.onCreated` event handler.

```
chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(
  (tab: Tab) => {
    const tabIndex = currentPages.findIndex((page) => page.tabId === tab.id);
    if(tabIndex === -1) {
      currentPages = [
        ..currentPages,
        {
          tabId: tab.id;
          startTime: new Date().toISOString();
          focus: [];
        }
      ]
    }
  }
)
```

So far so good. We've added the above mentioned event handlers. But at the time the `.onActivated` or `.onCreated` events are fired, it's not guaranteed that there'd be a url. So, when the url of the tabs are updated, the `.onUpdated` event is fired. That's why we need to change the code a little bit. We add an entry to the `visitedPages` only if the `tabExisting.url` exists (not null, undefined or '');

Lastly, in order to get all the tabs (an initialisation) from all the windows when the extension is installed, we should add another event handler like this:

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener((details) => {
  if(['install', 'chrome_update'].includes(details.reason)) {
    chrome.windows.getAll((windows: Window[]) => {
      windows.forEach(window => {
        chrome.tabs.getAllInWindow(window.id, (tabs: Tab[]) => {
          tabs.forEach(tab => {
            currentPages = [
              ..currentPages,
              {
                tabId: tab.id;
                startTime: new Date().toISOString();
                focus: [];
                url: tab.url;
              }
            ]
          });
        });
        chrome.tabs.query({active: true, windowId: window.id}, (tab: Tab) => {
          const tabIndex = currentPages.findIndex((page) => page.tabId === tab.id);
          if(tabIndex > 0) {
            currentPages[tabIndex - 1].active = true;
          }
        });
      });
    });
  }
  else if(details.reason == 'update') {
    //do whatever necessary 
  }
});
```

There can be many correct approaches to achieve this. This is how I think I'd do it. Please comment if anything is not clear.

Comment: This looks great! Let me try implementing and then I'll get back to you based on what I find out

Comment: yeah this doesn't work in some respects. Let me have a play around and I'll come back with where it's not working

Comment: I was just giving an idea how to do it. I'd be more than happy to help if you could show me what isn't working.

Comment: All good it works now :) The only thing is, would it be possible to integrate it in such a way that it would work with my existing code? So that, i'm tracking url changes, and active changes, so to speak?

Comment: Also - is there anyway to track if the user has become inactive? so if they're not using they're mouse or keyboard whatsoever for x amount of time say?

Comment: You just need to modify your type and add the listeners I wrote in your `background.js` and it should work. About tracking inactivity of a user, you can look at `chrome.idle`: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/idle/